# Problem with cross compilation of Paho C (ARM)

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, cmake, arm

I need help because I try to cross compile the paho library in c for my arm device.

I use an ubuntu 20.04 virtual machine and my cross compiler is gcc-linaro-5.3-2016.02-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf_5.3_sub1.0.3.tgz. Here the differents steps.

```
git clone https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.c.git

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential gcc make cmake cmake-gui cmake-curses-gui
sudo apt-get install fakeroot fakeroot devscripts dh-make lsb-release
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev 
sudo apt-get install doxygen graphviz
mkdir build.paho
cd build.paho
```

I've created a file "linaro.cmake" in the cmake folder of the paho project

```
 # specify the cross compiler

SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER    /opt/gcc-linaro-5.3-2016.02-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER  /opt/gcc-linaro-5.3-2016.02-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++)
SET(CMAKE_STRIP /opt/gcc-linaro-5.3-2016.02-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-strip)

#SET(OPENSSL_LIB_SEARCH_PATH opt/gcc-linaro-5.3-2016.02-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/lib)
#SET(OPENSSL_INC_SEARCH_PATH opt/gcc-linaro-5.3-2016.02-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/include/openssl)
#SET(OPENSSL_SEARCH_PATH "/opt/gcc-linaro-5.3-2016.02-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/lib;/opt/gcc-linaro-5.3-2016.02-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/bin/")

SET(OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR /opt/gcc-linaro-5.3-2016.02-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/bin)
SET(OPENSSL_LIBRARIES /opt/gcc-linaro-5.3-2016.02-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/lib)
#SET(OPENSSL_LIBRARIES /opt/gcc-linaro-5.3-2016.02-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/include/openssl)
SET(OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR /opt/gcc-linaro-5.3-2016.02-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/include/openssl)
SET(OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY /opt/gcc-linaro-5.3-2016.02-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/include/openssl/libcrypto.so)
SET(OPENSSL_SSL_LIBRARY /opt/gcc-linaro-5.3-2016.02-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/lib/libssl.so)

SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR arm)
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 1)
```

My problem, when I launch the command

```
cmake \
-GNinja \
-DPAHO_WITH_SSL=TRUE \
-DPAHO_BUILD_SAMPLES=TRUE \
-DPAHO_BUILD_DOCUMENTATION=TRUE \
-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../cmake/linaro.cmake ..
```

I have multiple warning like

> -- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.3.1
> -- Check for working C compiler: /opt/gcc-linaro-5.3-2016.02-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
> -- Check for working C compiler: /opt/gcc-linaro-5.3-2016.02-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
> -- works
> -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
> -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
> -- Detecting C compile features
> -- Detecting C compile features - done
> -- CMake version: 3.16.3
> -- CMake system name: Linux
> -- Timestamp is 2021-05-04T12:39:01Z
> -- Found OpenSSL: /opt/gcc-linaro-5.3-2016.02-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/bin/libcrypto.so
>
> -- Configuring done CMake Warning (dev) at src/CMakeLists.txt:200 (ADD_LIBRARY):   Policy CMP0028 is not set: Double colon in target
> name means ALIAS or   IMPORTED target.  Run "cmake --help-policy
> CMP0028" for policy details.   Use the cmake_policy command to set the
> policy and suppress this warning.
>
> Target "paho-mqtt3cs" links to target "OpenSSL::Crypto" but the
> target was   not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for
> an IMPORTED   target, or an ALIAS target is missing? This warning is
> for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
>
> CMake Warning (dev) at src/CMakeLists.txt:201 (ADD_LIBRARY):   Policy
> CMP0028 is not set: Double colon in target name means ALIAS or
> IMPORTED target.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0028" for policy
> details.   Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress
> this warning.
>
> Target "paho-mqtt3as" links to target "OpenSSL::Crypto" but the
> target was   not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for
> an IMPORTED   target, or an ALIAS target is missing? This warning is
> for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
>
> CMake Warning (dev) at src/CMakeLists.txt:332 (ADD_EXECUTABLE):
> Policy CMP0028 is not set: Double colon in target name means ALIAS or
> IMPORTED target.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0028" for policy
> details.   Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress
> this warning.
>
> Target "Sha1TestOpenSSL" links to target "OpenSSL::Crypto" but the
> target   was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for
> an IMPORTED   target, or an ALIAS target is missing? This warning is
> for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
>
> CMake Warning (dev) at src/CMakeLists.txt:323 (ADD_EXECUTABLE):
> Policy CMP0028 is not set: Double colon in target name means ALIAS or
> IMPORTED target.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0028" for policy
> details.   Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress
> this warning.
>
> Target "Base64TestOpenSSL" links to target "OpenSSL::Crypto" but the
> target   was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for
> an IMPORTED   target, or an ALIAS target is missing? This warning is
> for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
>
> CMake Warning (dev) at test/CMakeLists.txt:516 (ADD_EXECUTABLE):
> Policy CMP0028 is not set: Double colon in target name means ALIAS or
> IMPORTED target.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0028" for policy
> details.   Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress
> this warning.
>
> Target "test3" links to target "OpenSSL::Crypto" but the target was
> not   found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED
> target, or   an ALIAS target is missing? This warning is for project
> developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
>
> CMake Warning (dev) at test/CMakeLists.txt:1122 (ADD_EXECUTABLE):
> Policy CMP0028 is not set: Double colon in target name means ALIAS or
> IMPORTED target.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0028" for policy
> details.   Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress
> this warning.
>
> Target "test5" links to target "OpenSSL::Crypto" but the target was
> not   found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED
> target, or   an ALIAS target is missing? This warning is for project
> developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
>
> -- Generating done
> -- Build files have been written to: /home/myhome/Documents/paho.mqtt.c/build.paho

And when I try to launch ninja package

> [9/50] Linking C shared library src/libpaho-mqtt3cs.so.1.3.8 FAILED:
> src/libpaho-mqtt3cs.so.1.3.8  : &&
> /opt/gcc-linaro-5.3-2016.02-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
> -fPIC   -Wl,-init,MQTTClient_init -shared -Wl,-soname,libpaho-mqtt3cs.so.1 -o src/libpaho-mqtt3cs.so.1.3.8 src/CMakeFiles/common_ssl_obj.dir/MQTTTime.c.o
> src/CMakeFiles/common_ssl_obj.dir/MQTTProtocolClient.c.o
> src/CMakeFiles/common_ssl_obj.dir/Clients.c.o
> src/CMakeFiles/common_ssl_obj.dir/utf-8.c.o
> src/CMakeFiles/common_ssl_obj.dir/MQTTPacket.c.o
> src/CMakeFiles/common_ssl_obj.dir/MQTTPacketOut.c.o
> src/CMakeFiles/common_ssl_obj.dir/Messages.c.o
> src/CMakeFiles/common_ssl_obj.dir/Tree.c.o
> src/CMakeFiles/common_ssl_obj.dir/Socket.c.o
> src/CMakeFiles/common_ssl_obj.dir/Log.c.o
> src/CMakeFiles/common_ssl_obj.dir/MQTTPersistence.c.o
> src/CMakeFiles/common_ssl_obj.dir/Thread.c.o
> src/CMakeFiles/common_ssl_obj.dir/MQTTProtocolOut.c.o
> src/CMakeFiles/common_ssl_obj.dir/MQTTPersistenceDefault.c.o
> src/CMakeFiles/common_ssl_obj.dir/SocketBuffer.c.o
> src/CMakeFiles/common_ssl_obj.dir/LinkedList.c.o
> src/CMakeFiles/common_ssl_obj.dir/MQTTProperties.c.o
> src/CMakeFiles/common_ssl_obj.dir/MQTTReasonCodes.c.o
> src/CMakeFiles/common_ssl_obj.dir/Base64.c.o
> src/CMakeFiles/common_ssl_obj.dir/SHA1.c.o
> src/CMakeFiles/common_ssl_obj.dir/WebSocket.c.o
> src/CMakeFiles/common_ssl_obj.dir/StackTrace.c.o
> src/CMakeFiles/common_ssl_obj.dir/Heap.c.o
> src/CMakeFiles/paho-mqtt3cs.dir/MQTTClient.c.o
> src/CMakeFiles/paho-mqtt3cs.dir/SSLSocket.c.o
> /opt/gcc-linaro-5.3-2016.02-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/lib/libssl.so  -lOpenSSL::Crypto  -lc  -ldl  -lpthread  -lrt && : /opt/gcc-linaro-5.3-2016.02-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/5.3.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld :
> ne peut trouver -lOpenSSL::Crypto collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit
> status [11/50] Building C object
> src/CMakeFiles/paho-mqtt3as.dir/SSLSocket.c.o ninja: build stopped:
> subcommand failed.

Have anybody an idea ?

The strange thing for me is this line
-- Found OpenSSL: /opt/gcc-linaro-5.3-2016.02-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/bin/libcrypto.so even if I indicated another location.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you consider recompiling a more recent GCC cross-compiler from the source code of GCC?

Comment: Thanks, I've tested with the linaro compiler because it's a requirement of my product provider. They launch a new firmware and I've tested with a recent GCC compiler it's ok (gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-arm-linux-gnueabihf). I just have to upgrade all my devices

Comment: Then discuss by email with your product provider. If they give some C++ code, and if the license allows you to recompile that C++ code, you could use a newer GCC compiler.

Comment: BTW, the current GCC is [GCC 11](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-11/) released at end of April 2021. Why can't you use it?

Comment: My hardware provider ((https://www.owasys.com/en/products/owa450) have a main FS based in Debian 10.6 - Kernel based in Linux kernel 4.19.94 - Crosscompiler based in gcc8.3. He deliver his hardware with his own libraries (GPS / GSM / IO / ...) so when I use his libraries in my software I have to use the same ccompilation tool kit

Comment: No, technically you could compile GCC from its [source code](https://gcc.gnu.org/mirrors.html), and use your GCC with libraries provided with your hardware. Maybe you are not allowed to do so, and yes, compiling GCC from source code may take you a few days. See e.g. http://linuxfromscratch.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved with a new compiler gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-arm-linux-gnueabihf.